# Does there exist a non-hyperelliptic Riemann surface with automorphism group $C_2\times A_4$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, riemann-surfaces

Does there exist a non-hyperelliptic Riemann surface of genus 5 with automorphism group $C_2\times A_4$?

Answer (score 3):

One thing that should be made more precise is whether you are asking that the automorphism group *equals* $C_2 \times A_4$ or if it is enough that it *contains* $C_2 \times A_4$. I'm assuming you mean the former. Then it seems that the answer is *no*. In the paper "The locus of curves with prescribed automorphism group" (K. Magaard, T. Shaska, S. Shpectorov, H. Voelklein, http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205314) one finds a classification of loci in the moduli space $M_g$ of curves with "large" automorphism group for small genus, meaning that the order of the automorphism group is at least $4(g-1)$. In this classification we see that there is a unique 1-dimensional family in $M_5$ of curves with full automorphism group $C_2 \times A_4$. By combining with the results of "Some special families of hyperelliptic curves" (T. Shaska, http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1867) it seems that all those are hyperelliptic.

PS - I remember that there is an error in one of the tables in the paper of Kuribayashi and Kimura referenced by Igor Rivin - proceed with caution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-hyperelliptic (fixed-point free) involution of the surface of genus $5,$ with the quotient a surface of genus $3.$ Further, $A_4$ does come up as the automorphism group thereof, [see](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/443727bb-27cd-41ca-ba96-8aec175385d1/eb99cdf97d58f161c6a856bfba80eb11)

*S. Allen Broughton*, MR 1090743 [**Classifying finite group actions on surfaces of low genus**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(91)90021-S), *J. Pure Appl. Algebra* **69** (1991), no. 3, 233--270.

So, modulo some care, the answer seems to be YES.

**ADDITION** As pointed out by Noam in the comments, the above is not quite satisfying. The simplest reference is one to t[he paper of Kuribayashi and Kimura](https://www.evernote.com/l/ABhoritVc3dDkq1BL_piYVCkr7dKhoZcDdw)

*Akikazu Kuribayashi and Hideyuki Kimura*, MR 1068416 [**Automorphism groups of compact Riemann surfaces of genus five**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(90)90212-7), *J. Algebra* **134** (1990), no. 1, 80--103.
Unfortunately, that paper's notation is somewhat hard to penetrate. On the other hand, the way they describe the automorphism group (conjugacy class in $GL()$ should make it easy to check that the relevant surface is not hyperelliptic.

Comment: But an unramified double cover $C$ of a genus-3 curve $C$ does not necessarily have automorphism group $C_2 \times {\rm Aut}(C )$: even if the fixed-point-free involution is unique (is that automatic for $C'$ of genus $5$?), some automorphisms of $C$ might not lift to $C'$, and even if all of ${\rm Aut}( C)$ lifts to ${\rm Aut}(C')$  the resulting exact sequence $1 \to C_2 \to {\rm Aut}(C') \to {\rm Aut}(C ) \to 1$ might not split.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Your points are well taken...